# Who is the daughter of this table?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have a program with over 800 lines of code. This program has many input and output tables and some are independent of other tables.
I have to modify some intermediate tables but I don't know which final tables will be affected as there are many merges, subquerys etc. Is there any way to find out what the daughter table? I'm sorry about my English.

```
data have1;
set have;
run;

data have2;
set have1;
run;

data have1;
set have;
run;

data have3;
set have2;
run;


proc sql;
  create table have4 as
  select *
  from have1, have3;
quit;

data have5;
set have2;
run;
```

If I modify the have1 table, what are their daughter tables?.

have1 -> have2 -> have3 -> have4
have1 -> have2 -> have5 
Thank you.

Comment: Try PROC SCAPROC for starters, it may help you trace it out. Besides that, you're sort of out of luck. Macro variables and shortcut lists means even searching the text can't guarantee what tables are affected.

Comment: You could try rewriting the code in Enterprise Guide and creating a process flow with a node for each step -- this is not automatic.  The ancestors and dependents will become visible in the process flow diagram.

Comment: This program is written in Enterprise Guide, I have used the option Analyze Program Flow. And i can see the diagram but the program has got a hundred table output and i can´t see the flow is very hard. Thx.